# The system cannot find the path specified - text file

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, text-files

I added a text file to my project as in this path:

Myproject/WebPages/stopwords.txt

Image:
http://s7.postimg.org/w65vc3lx7/Untitled.png

I tried to open the file, but i can't !

My code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("stopwords.txt"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();
```

Error: 
  stopwords.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: Please describe in detail how you're running this program. What is your current working directory, and where is this file relative to that directory?

Comment: @Kenster, i added an image , check it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like,

I guess that you are in *.jsp* file.

```
<%

String path = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WebContent/stopwords.txt") ;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
// other codes...
 %>
```

**EDITED :**

```
<% 
  String path = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/stopwords.txt") ;
  //check here with print path variable...    
  // you can pass this path variable to invoke method which is reside into //your java class...
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));


%>
```

Comment: No , i'm in Java class in the project !

Comment: @belal , shall i guess where you type the code into servlet/plain java class ?

Comment: last question, are you building J2EE application or J2SE project ?

Comment: please, use my above code it will 100% work, only need is, while you are caling specific method into java-class then pass this path into that method parameter. Above my code either servlet or jsp able to execute successfully. so use accordingly.

Comment: i added an image , check it !

Comment: Kindly check my EDITED code, which should be worked 100%. if my answer satiesfied with your reqirement then kindly accept my answer and upvote too. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The FileReader will be opening the file relative to the path this is executed from. If this is being executed from the "MyProject" folder, you will need to specify the folder in the FileReader constructor as in `FileReader("WebPages/stopWords.txt")`

Answer (score 0):

If your projectpath is the root folder. Where the class is isn't where the root folder is. Changing it to this should work.  You also need to add a space to your filename.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Web Pages/stopwords.txt"));
```

Comment: Last thing i can think of is to make sure that's exactly your path even the capitals matter in the file path.

Comment: i added an image , check it !

Comment: Yes you needed to add spaces. If this is correct please upvote it or mark as answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

empirical method:

begin to create and write some file => then you will see where it is on the filesystem

then place you file in the same directory, and retry others methods to read it

warning: sometimes, you cant read or write in some directories.